# What is this guy doing at FOH?

Tags: live-sound

I noticed this guy at front of house during Alkaline Trio's set the other day.

[image: Guy at FOH]

He was sitting next to the mixing console with a rack in front of him holding what looked like a Guitar Hero controller. After the set he stood up and put it in a little gig bag. I wasn't quick enough to get a photo of the front of it, but it was a guitar-shaped controller with buttons on the neck and no headstock.

I didn't hear anything that wasn't coming from the three guys on stage (like synth parts or anything). Alkaline plays a pretty straight- forward set without a bunch of heavy effects or anything. Each of the guys had stomp-boxes on stage but nothing that sounded particularly elaborate.

What could this guy have been doing?

Comment: Midi to DMX controller?

Comment: @Tetsujin They didn't have a light show. It was daylight during their set. There were just a couple of overhead spots on the whole show.